How to do some performance tuning in elastic search query
I use spring data reactive framework to query elastic search and it was very slow.
The data total volume is around 1,200,000.
I need to query around 400,000 (around 1/3 of total) once a time, by one date field.
Spring data framework will create scroll to query again and again. It will cost 90 sec which is very slow and make client request timeout issue.
We have increase the timeout setup as short term solution. But we still want to see if any way we could do some performance tuning.
Is there any way we could check the performance in ES index?
Is there any way we could increase the performance in the ES world, like in DB, which we could add index to increase the query speed?
My dependency
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.7.18")

Thanks

which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use?
